# RegEx after certain string

Tags: regex, string, powershell, text

I have a manifest file

```
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: BundleSample
Bundle-Version: 4
```

I want to change the value of Bundle-Name using -replace in Powershell.
I used this pattern `Bundle-Name:(.*)`
But it returns including the Bundle-Name. What would be the pattern if I want to change only the value of the Bundle-Name?

Comment: If you want help for your code, **show** your code in a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture both the `Bundle-Name:` and its value in two separate capture groups.
Then replace like this:

```
$manifest = @"
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: BundleSample
Bundle-Version: 4
"@

$newBundleName = 'BundleTest'

$manifest -replace '(Bundle-Name:\s*)(.*)', ('$1{0}' -f $newBundleName)

# or
# $manifest -replace '(Bundle-Name:\s*)(.*)', "`$1$newBundleName"
```

The above will result in

> ```
> Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
> Bundle-Name: BundleTest
> Bundle-Version: 4
> ```

Regex details:

```
(                   Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   Bundle-Name:     Match the character string “Bundle-Name:” literally (case sensitive)
   \s               Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line)
      *             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
(                   Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   .                Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed)
      *             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

---

Thanks to [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings), there is even an easier regex that can be used:

```
$manifest -replace '(?<=Bundle-Name:\s*).*', $newBundleName
```

This uses a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

The regex details for that are:

```
(?<=                Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
   Bundle-Name:     Match the characters “Bundle-Name:” literally
   \s               Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
      *             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
.                   Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Comment: Easier with a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `$manifest -replace '(?<=Bundle-Name: ).*',$newBundleName`

Comment: @LotPings Yes, that's a beaut. I have added your regex to the answer. Hope you don't mind.